# Induced map in cohomology of a covering

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fiber-bundles

Is it true that if $p: E \to B$ is a $2$-fold covering, the map $p^*$ induced in cohomology is surjective?

Answer (score 1):

If $E=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{3\}$ and $p(x)=3$ for both $x\in E$, then $p^*\colon H^0(B) \to H^0(E)\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}^2$ is the map $n\mapsto (n,n)$ which is not surjective.

Comment: As an aside, it is pretty much never surjective (in all degrees). Even the doubling map on the circle induces the map $n\mapsto 2n$ in degree $1$ which misses all the odd integers.